# heroku set UTF-8

Tags: php, mysql, heroku, cleardb

I have a db with heroku (clearDB).
From my php page the € symbol I see it correctly.

[image]

Bu inside the DB (with MYSQL Workbench)
[image]

The `heroku config:add LANG=en_US.UTF-8` not help me.

how can i solve? same error for accented letters

Comment: You should be storing the price number (12.00) as a numeric in a seperate column to the (I assume) description

Comment: "same error for accented letters"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: no.............

Comment: Why not, specifically? Have you implemented all of the recommendations?

Comment: Ok, it's done! :)